# foreach actitivity in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there any method available in Azure data factory to exit the for each loop. I am using a for each loop to iterate through files and to process it. But when the copy activity placed inside the loop fails, the loop executes multiple times to reprocess the failed file. I think it has to do something with the number of files available in the Get meta data array. Can anyone suggest a method to resolve this issue.

Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Jay Gong said that Data factory doesn't support break the loop if the inner copy active failed!

Others have created a [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory?query=foreach) for data factory, it have been vote up 14 times.

But still with no response. :
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Even I have created a variable and if condition to exit out of the loop.

Comment: @SandeepT No, we can't. Even you have create the variable and `if-condition` in Foreach active, you must set the expression(return boolean value) compare the variable with current foreach item. Then you need add active in true or false condition. If condition true, run copy active for current item, if false,  do nothing(there isn't any active support break loop). Then loop next item. Even in true condition,  the copy active for current item still may be failed. I think you can understand what I said.

Comment: @SandeepT If you don't believe me, you can still waiting for other answer. It doesn't matter.  If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you @Leon,that solution was working fine for me. We had couple of loop operations prior to this particular loop, so we were looking to better the performance of the pipeline. So if we could exit the loop if an error occurs, that may enhance the performance of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can't break the ForEach loop, but you can cancel the entire pipeline running that ForEach via the Rest API in case of an error. Will add example code in a blog post next week.
[image]